# AWS Rails install fails: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-ami

I am installing rails 5 on aws. I have installed rvm and ruby. Ruby version I installed is 2.3.1. I have done bundle install.

Now I am trying to install rails 5 by using command - **'sudo gem install rails --version 5.0.0'**

But I am getting error

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

**rvm list**

```
=* ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

Complete log on running command - **'sudo gem install rails --version 5.0.0'**

```
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: minitest-5.10.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.10.1
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.2
Fetching: activesupport-5.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

Why it is showing ruby version required >= 2.2.2 ? What should I do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using rvm, you should install gems for the current user. That means **without** `sudo`.

```
gem install rails --version 5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I updated my Ruby version to the latest 3.2.2, the latest available (presently). Use "rbenv install --l" to check for the latest version.

`brew install rbenv ruby-build rbenv init                                                                eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"                                                                      rbenv install --l                                                                                 rbenv install 3.2.2                                                                       rbenv global 3.2.2`