# activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2. even though I have ruby 2.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Why I get this error in my Ubuntu server?

```
rails@myapp:~/www/digitalshelving/current$ rvm use  ruby-2.4.0@5.1
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0 with gemset 5.1
rails@myapp:~/www/digitalshelving/current$ ruby -v

ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

rails@myapp:~/www/digitalshelving/current$ sudo gem install rails --version=5.1.5
[sudo] password for rails: 
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
rails@myapp:~/www/digitalshelving/current$
```

And same result with ruby 2.4.1:

```
rails@myapp:/home$ sudo gem install rails -v 5.1.5
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
rails@myapp:/home$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

I can't find any sense

Thanks

Comment: What if you try to install Rails without using sudo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Rails install fails: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085525/aws-rails-install-fails-activesupport-requires-ruby-version-2-2-2)

Comment: The problem is that without sudo I don't have writable permission...¿? I had to create the rvm gemset with `rvmsudo rvm gemset create...` because I don't have writeable acces

Comment: I have the installation in `/usr/local/rvm/rubies` and `/usr/local/rvm/gems`, that is how is in the production server

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here:
https://rvm.io/integration/sudo

in etc/sudoers comment:

```
# comment out:
# Defaults  secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# add:
Defaults env_keep +="rvm_bin_path GEM_HOME IRBRC MY_RUBY_HOME rvm_path rvm_prefix rvm_version GEM_PATH rvmsudo_secure_path RUBY_VERSION rvm_ruby_string rvm_delete_flag"
```

After that, if I `run sudo ruby -v` I get the rvm selected ruby version